# Error message shown to user when invalid credentials

Tags: javascript, html

right now I'm trying to make an error message shown to the user if the login credentials are wrong and I just can't get it to work. I use node.js and SQLite for my database. I tried fetching, importing, and exporting but nothing worked. I won't share my front-end code because nothing in there works.

Here's my whole back-end: https://pastebin.com/SaQrGq4z
And here's the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>club</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>

    </header>
    <div id="ClockDisplay" class="clock" onload="showTime()"></div>
    <div class="background">
        <div class="demo">
            <div class="login">
                <div class="login-text">
                    <span class="glitchanim" data-text=".club"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="login-form">
                    <form action="auth" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                        <div class="login-row">
                            <svg class="login-icon name svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path d="M0,20 a10,8 0 0,1 20,0z M10,0 a4,4 0 0,1 0,8 a4,4 0 0,1 0,-8" />
                            </svg>
                            <style type="text/css">
                                input[name="username"] {
                                    background: transparent;
                                }
                            </style>
                            <input type="text" name="username" class="login-input name" id="test"
                                placeholder="Username" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="login-row">
                            <svg class="login-icon pass svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path d="M0,20 20,20 20,8 0,8z M10,13 10,16z M4,8 a6,8 0 0,1 12,0" />
                            </svg>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="login-input pass" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                        <p class="login-error">Username and/or Password do not exist</p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
                        <p class="login-signup">Don't have an account? &NonBreakingSpace; <a href="signup.html">Sign
                                up</a></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```